# Can't remove the billboards from my scene correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, cocos3d

I need to remove the billboards and the textures in `Cocos3D` - I try to use this method:

```
-(void)cleanUpPanoramaOnScene:(AxPanoramaScene *)scene {

    for (AxBillboard *billboard in [[scene->billboards copy] autorelease]) {
        CCTexture2D *texture =  ((CCSprite *)billboard.billboard).texture;
        [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] removeTexture: texture];
        [scene removeChild: billboard];
    }
    [scene->billboards removeAllObjects];
}
```

but it is failing with exception:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <__NSArrayM: 0xfeb5f10> was mutated while being enumerated.'
```

The array is:

```
<__NSArrayM 0xfeb5f10>(
AxBillboard 'Unnamed':268,
AxBillboard 'Unnamed':275,
AxBillboard 'Unnamed':276,
AxBillboard 'Unnamed':283,
...
```

Can't understand the root cause of this issue. Any help?

Comment: Why are you creating an autorelease copy of the array? That seems superfluous. The error you get is from mutating an array (ie add/delete elements) while enumerating it. A common fix is to enumerate backwards using reverseObjectEnumerator. Unless this is somehow related to copy/autorelease I wager the problem is within the removeChild code. Add exception breakpoint to see what line it crashes.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D the exception in taking place before removeChild. In the first line of "for" cycle. I making the copy of the NSMutableArray - I think than nothing can change it.

Comment: are you running this in the background / on a separate thread?

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Unbelievable! U're right - forget to send the completion of the block to the main thread and the method is loaded in a background thread. Very big thanks!